# Producing cloud and cloud shadow mask from Sentinel images?

Tags: software-recommendations, sentinel-snap, shadow

What is a good tool to produce (cloud) and cloud shadow masks?

I tried fmask tool and Sentinel SNAP but while those can produce reasonable cloud masks, cloud shadow results are poor.

I need to produce cloud shadow mask to mask such pixels in my final output.

Comment: You know that cloud mask is included in Level-1C right? https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-2-msi/level-1c/cloud-masks

Comment: Thanks @BERA. Will check it out! Though I need cloud shadow mask more